# Akka.NET query actors efficiently

Tags: task-parallel-library, akka.net

I'm creating a proof of concept with Akka.NET for a production project but I'm facing a query concept understanding problem.

Situation is a follows:
CoordinatorActor has a list of thousands of `Hotel-Actors`.

I would like to query all `Hotel-Actors` for all hotels with a room available on a specific date.

Of course I could foreach through them and sent a `.Ask<>` request for the specific date. Holding a reference of all the tasks and do a `Task.WhenAll(requests)`. But that feels a little unnatural.

Alternatively I could send a broadcast message with a request for the specific date to all hotels at once (ActorSelection or router), but then I don't know when they **all** responded back with a `Tell` message.

Does anyone has a suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the real scenario? That would make it easier to recommend a suitable solution.

Comment: The scenario is a booking site that has a lot of hotels, the user should see available hotels on a specific date. The criteria if the hotel is available are fairly complex and dynamic of nature.

Also sub-selections like only hotels in a specific area should be possible.

Comment: Is the hotel "database" even a good case for Akka? Seems like some normal data structures would be enough and have less overhead. If you need to interrogate all hotels all the time then one actor per hotel also seems questionable.

Comment: The criteria of availability are not static but also based on booking-user history and trends. Ever HotelActor can make this dissension on its own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your feelings are right here. Using Ask for communication between actors is considered highly inefficient - mostly because of each ask needs to allocate separate message listener.

First good question would be: do you need to wait for them all to respond back? Maybe responses can be emitted as they come.

In case, when you need to collect all of the data before replying, you need to have some way of counting all messages in order to guarantee if some of them are still pending - in that case using `ActorSelection` is not feasible. You'll need counter or list of identifiers that could be associated with each message - while they can be even ordinary numbers, usually `IActorRef`s are easier to work with.

Below you can see simplified example of `Aggregator` actor that can be created for this particular task - it will automatically return all replies, it received, and stop itself, once there are no more messages to wait for or a timeout has occurred.

```csharp
class Aggregator<T> : ReceiveActor
{
    private IActorRef originalSender;
    private ISet<IActorRef> refs;

    public Aggregator(ISet<IActorRef> refs)
    {
        this.refs = refs;
        // this operation will finish after 30 sec of inactivity
        // (when no new message arrived)
        Context.SetReceiveTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        ReceiveAny(x =>
        {
            originalSender = Sender;
            foreach (var aref in refs) aref.Tell(x);
            Become(Aggregating);
        });
    }

    private void Aggregating()
    {
        var replies = new List<T>();
        // when timeout occurred, we reply with what we've got so far
        Receive<ReceiveTimeout>(_ => ReplyAndStop(replies));
        Receive<T>(x =>
        {
            if (refs.Remove(Sender)) replies.Add(x);
            if (refs.Count == 0) ReplyAndStop(replies);
        });
    }

    private void ReplyAndStop(List<T> replies)
    {
        originalSender.Tell(new AggregatedReply<T>(replies));
        Context.Stop(Self);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer and code! Indeed I need to make sure all actors return otherwise the result is not guaranteed correct. I found out that the Ask<> on high number of hotelActors (1M) indeed can cause a Out of memory exception. 

I've used a database to query hotels on criteria (area, stars etc) and select the string of the ActorPath (witch is static). This way only relevant hotelActors are requested for availability.

Btw maybe this code isn't safe for parallel request?

Comment: This example assumes, that your creating one actor per aggregated query. It's automatically downed. 

When it comes to correctness guarantees, this depends on the use case - incomplete answer isn't always a bad one, i.e. from the perspective of hotel searching having displaying 100 out of 120 correct answers is still better than displaying red message with "sorry, we couldn't fulfill your request".