# How to combine the responses of two asynchronous services responses data in Akka.Net

Tags: akka.net

I am making two asynchronous service calls via two actors

Actor 1 - > Fetch Data -> This will return some response

Actor 2 - > Fetch Data -> This will return some response.

How do I combine both of the results in Akka.Net. Is there is any pattern which we need to follow in Akka.net?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use ask pattern:

```csharp
ReceiveAsync<Message>(async msg => {
    var t1 = actor1.Ask<Response>(new Request(), cancellationToken);
    var t2 = actor2.Ask<Response>(new Request(), cancellationToken);
    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
    DoSomething(t1.Result, t2.Result);
});
```

This approach will do the job, but it has few downsides:

1. It will block an actor from processing any other messages until the entire method finishes execution (including completion of both `t1` and `t2`).
2. It makes use of `Ask` which has its own performance implication - not big when compared to eg. database I/O, but in many scenarios it can be too much (if ofc you bother about performance).

A way to address point 1 is to move from `await`:

```csharp
Receive<Message>(msg => {
    var t1 = actor1.Ask<Response>(new Request(), cancellationToken);
    var t2 = actor2.Ask<Response>(new Request(), cancellationToken);
    Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).ContinueWith(t => {
        var t1 = t.Result[0];
        var t2 = t.Result[1];
        return new CombinedResponse(t1.Result, t2.Result);
    }).PipeTo(Self, sender: Sender);
});
Receive<CombinedResponse>(resp => DoSomething(resp.Result1, resp.Result2));
```

This will not require from actor to wait until both tasks complete, making it free to process other messages in the meantime. This however still uses Tasks and Ask.

Finally it's possible to use only core akka primitives and simply aggregate the partial responses by yourself. This can often be done using so called [Aggregator pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105339/akka-net-query-actors-efficiently). There are multiple ways of achieving it, but basically they all operate on similar model:

- Keep count on how many actors need to respond for a complete response.
- Keep partial responses in a buffer (list), that will be filled with incoming responses from other actors. When an actor responded, reduce the number of actors to await for. Once that number reaches 0, you've assembled a complete response.
- Keep an info about the original `Sender` actor that requested for complete response, so you can send it the result (if necessary), once a full response was assembled.
- Use `Context.ReceiveTimeout` prevent waiting infinitely in case if some of the responses may not arrive for any reason.